# Resize with zoom and floating div

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a wrap div which contain a div with jCarousel and near the div, two Arrows used to change the picture.

The problem is that when I resize browser or zoom in or out, the Arrow moves and go over and under the jcarousel div.

why it happens like this? Here is an example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Wbt83/

Comment: Your example is messy. A well formatted question receives a good response...

Comment: I update my fiddle. Actually the problem is just that, when i resize the browser, the 2 Arrow that i put left and right the image, change position and go over and under the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't simulate what you ara having trouble with, but here is the correct `flow` for responsive design:

The `pseudo` CSS for your project:

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;   // Your custom width here
    height: 300px; // Custom height
}

.wrapper .jcarousell{
    [...] // jCarousell specif css
}

.wrapper .arrow{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;     // Custom top spacing for arrows
    height: 20px; // Arrow height
    width: 20px;  // Arrow width
}

.wrapper .arrow-left{
    left: 0;
}

.wrapper .arrow-right{
    right: 0;
}
```

The pseudo `HTML` for your project:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="jcarousell">
        <li>[...]</li>
        <li>[...]</li>
        <li>[...]</li>
    </ul>

    <img class="arrow arrow-left" src="leftArrow.png"/>
    <img class="arrow arrow-right" src="rightArrow.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. actually i just started with css and i didn't know u could put 2 classes in declaration of css. I solved using position:absolute for Arrow, and working with the margin to make everything fit. I don't know if it's not an elegant solution, but now when i resize my browser, Arrow don't move anymore.

Comment: Read this, and you will be just fine with HTML and CSS: http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/

Comment: Accepted. Anyway, floating the 2 arrow Arrow and div to left and setting left Arrow_left margin, left div margin and left Arrow_right margin, so everything is in place, is a bad code solution?

Comment: Absolute positioning is best. If your carousell one day increase size, you would need to increase the margin... Read what I sent to you, and you will understand